# How to access room database in service

Tags: android, android-service, android-room, android-livedata

I am having problem with observing LiveData and querying data from Room Database in a foreground service class. This service run in the background and perform various database operations.

Observing LiveData seems possible by using `observeForever` and 
querying can be done by accessing repository class (bypassing ViewModel) but it seems like a hack, not a standard way.

Comment: Same here, did you have solution for this problem?